# How to use Apples Core Image with opengl es

Tags: ios, objective-c, graphics, opengl-es

So I have a texture (in a framebuffer) in my opengl es game, and I have been wanting to blur it.  I have been trying many methods to see which one will get me the best FPS as this needs to happen real-time as the texture is constantly changing.

How exactly could I take a opengles texture and send it to coreImage, then back to opengles for display?

This is some code that basically you put in a UIImage and it returns a blurred one. Where I am stuck is getting that texture to a UIImage, and I am wondering if their is a better way then loading in the new UIImage each time.

```
- (UIImage *)blurredImageWithImage:(UIImage *)sourceImage{

    //  Create our blurred image
    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:sourceImage.CGImage];

    //  Setting up Gaussian Blur
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
    [filter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:15.0f] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
    CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];

    /*  CIGaussianBlur has a tendency to shrink the image a little, this ensures it matches 
     *  up exactly to the bounds of our original image */
    CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:[inputImage extent]];

    UIImage *retVal = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    return retVal;
}
```

As shown by this graph core image could potentially be even better then the most efficient methods.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you haven't tried and noticed already, the method you quoted will *kill* performance — to create a `UIImage` from a GL texture, you need to read a bunch of pixels off the GPU and into CPU memory. CoreImage might then send it to the GPU to perform its effects, but since you're getting a `UIImage` out of that, you're reading back from the GPU again, before sending your image back into the GPU for use as a texture. That's four data transfers per frame, and each one is expensive.

Instead, keep Core Image on the GPU, and don't use intermediate `UIImage`s.

1. You'll need to keep a `CIContext` around for rendering, so create one early on from your GL context with [`contextWithEAGLContext:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CIContext/contextWithEAGLContext:) and hang onto it.
2. Use [`imageWithTexture:size:flipped:colorSpace:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CIImage/imageWithTexture:size:flipped:colorSpace:) to create a `CIImage` from your GL texture.
3. When you want to render the result of a filter chain to a GL texture, bind it with `glBindFramebuffer` (just as you would if you were making your own render-to-texture pass), and draw the filter's output `CIImage` in your `CIContext` with [`drawImage:inRect:fromRect:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CIContext/drawImage:inRect:fromRect:). (And don't forget to rebind that texture before using it to perform other GL rendering.)

This is pretty well covered in a WWDC talk from way back in 2012: [Core Image Techniques](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012-511/). The discussion starts around 40:00 with code and demo following through about 46:05. But stick around for the rest of the talk after that and you'll get lots more demos, inspiration, code and architecture tips for fun things you can do with CoreImage in GL to make a game look awesome.

Also, if you render using Metal (), there are corresponding CoreImage APIs for doing the same workflow there (`contextWithMTLDevice:` and `imageWithMTLTexture:`).

Comment: Should we use the same EAGLContext for OpenGL rendering and core image rendering, or we can have separate contexts for the two? My aim is to render one view using OpenGLES and another subview using Core Image filter.

Comment: If you have two separate GL workflows (like two unrelated views), use two separate GL contexts. If you have one rendering process in one view, where for part of your work you want to use Core Image — like applying a filter to a result from 3D rendering — use a single GL context.

Comment: In one of the main view, I take the video frame from camera and render it to OpenGL view. In another subview I wish to show histogram of this video frame, which may be computed using Core Image filter or a custom Opengles filter. Should I use a single GL Context?

Comment: That sounds like you have some data sharing that needs to go on, which would suggest a single context. It also sounds more like material for asking a new question rather than extended comment discussion on a tangentially related answer.